# Required is "not matching" if not at least 1 character matches in a sequence of 3 otherwise optional regex expressions

Tags: .net, regex, windows

I have a quite lengthy regex consisting of 3 parts, all of which are optional, but have the prerequisite, that at least one single character of them must be matched.

For brevity, let's call these 3 long sections (A), (B) and (C).

Currently, they are encoded this way:

```
(A)?(B)?(C)?
```

which does not enforce the prerequisite, of course.

I know, that I can do

```
((A)(B)?(C)?)|((A)?(B)(C)?)|((A)?(B)?(C))
```

in each `Or` branch making one part mandatory.

But as these expressions are truly lengthy, I would end up with quite a mess.

Is there a qualifier of some sort to enforce that on `((A)?(B)?(C)?)` directly (i.e., not matching if not at least 1 character matched)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead to check the presence of at least one of the sections.

```
(?=A|B|C)(A)?(B)?(C)?
```

This matches only, if the next sequence is either `A` or `B` or `C`. In any other case (where `(A)?(B)?(C)?` would match an empty string), there will be no match due to the lookahead.

This has the downside, that your sequences are sequences are checked twice - but I don't really know any way around that.

Comment: +1 for the attempt, thanks :) (There's also stuff going on before and after the sequence, which might complicate the lookahead...)